# How to disable quarantine mode in CLI for TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, command-line-interface, testcafe

We have quarantine mode enabled in our .testcaferc file. We've just started implementing visual testing with applitools, but because of how the checks work with applitools, when quarantine mode is enabled, we're wasting checks on failing tests.

We want to run our visual tests with a script that would overwrite some config key:values, but haven't found documentation on how to disable quarantine mode via CLI.

I've tried -q false, -q=false, --quarantine-mode false, --quarantine-mode=false.

We can't set attempts or success to 0 as they need to be > 0 and attempts needs to be > success.

The only other option I can think of is to create a whole separate config just for visual testing, which we find to be a tad unneeded when a script is much easier.

Can anyone shine some light on how a CLI command can be written to disable quarantine mode?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't implemented yet. As a workaround, you also can delete the quarantine option from the config and assign it with CLI only for the required tests. We will inform you in [this issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7077) once it is implemented